# Sort table in Angular Material 8

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I am new to angular and started building after going through the videos and referring to the docs.
Pagination works perfectly fine but I have problem sorting the table. I have tried the following.

component.html

```
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

        <!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let environment"> <a for="env" id="env"
                (click)="openEditDialog(environment)">{{environment.environmentName}}</a> </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- URL Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="URL">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> URL </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let environment"> {{environment.url}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Username Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Username">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Username </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let environment"> {{environment.userName}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Details Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Details">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Details </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let environment"> {{environment.details}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Delete Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Delete">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Delete </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let environment"><a for="deleteEnvironment" id="deleteEnvironment"
                (click)="deleteEnvironment(environment._id)">
                <mat-icon style="color: #d2002b;">delete_forever</mat-icon>
            </a> </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
    <mat-paginator style="bottom: 0px; position: sticky;" [length]="100" [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" showFirstLastButtons>
        </mat-paginator>
```

Here's my component.ts file

```
            import { Component, OnInit, Inject, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
            import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
            import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
            import {EnvironmentService} from '../../services/environment.service';
            import {Environment} from '../../services/environment.model';
            import {MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';
            import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
            import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';

            export interface DialogData {  
              environment: string;    
              dialogTitle: string;
            }

            @Component({
              selector: 'app-environment',
              templateUrl: './environment.component.html',
              styleUrls: ['./environment.component.css'],
              providers: [EnvironmentService] 
            })
            export class EnvironmentComponent implements OnInit {
              environmentDetailsForm: FormGroup;
              serverErrorMessages : string;
              environments: Environment[] = []; 
              displayedColumns = ['Name', 'URL', 'Username', 'Details', 'Delete'];

              // dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Environment>;
              dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.environments);

              @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
              @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

              constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
                private environmentService:EnvironmentService,
                private router: Router,
                private dialog: MatDialog) { }

              ngOnInit() {
                this.environmentDetailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({});
                this.loadAllEnvironments();
                this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
              }
            private loadAllEnvironments() {
                this.environmentService.getEnvironmentDetails()
                .subscribe(environments => {
                  this.environments = environments; 
                  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.environments);
                  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
                });
                return this.environments;
            }
}
```

app.module.ts file

```
import { MatTableModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatSortModule } from from '@angular/material';

imports: [
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule
]
```

I am getting Up and down arrows on clicking the table headers and **there is no error in the console**. But the sorting functionality didn't work. If something is missing, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I knew what was missing. Had to specify **mat-sort-header="*some name*"** so that I can compare using that name in the switch case mentioned by @tommytarheel. We can do it this way.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="name"> Name </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let environment"> <a for="env" id="env"
            (click)="openEditDialog(environment)">{{environment.environmentName}}</a> </td>
    </ng-container>
```

Instead of

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let environment"> <a for="env" id="env"
            (click)="openEditDialog(environment)">{{environment.environmentName}}</a> </td>
    </ng-container>
```

And in .ts file, as @tommytarheel mentioned, I have to make sortData function exactly same as he defined in his answer.

```
// import Sort:
import {Sort} from '@angular/material/sort';

// define function to handle sorting:
sortData(sort: Sort) {
    const data = this.environments.slice();
    if (!sort.active || sort.direction === '') {
        this.dataSource = data;
        return;
    }

    this.dataSource = data.sort((a, b) => {
        const isAsc = sort.direction === 'asc';
        switch (sort.active) {
            case 'name': return compare(a.name, b.name, isAsc);
            case 'username': return compare(a.username, b.username, isAsc);
            default: return 0;
        }
    });
}

function compare(a: number | string, b: number | string, isAsc: boolean) { 
    return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the only thing you're missing is to link the matSortChange event to a function in your typescript for sorting.  Try something like this:

In your HTML:

```
<mat-table matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)" />
```

In your TypeScript:

```
// import Sort:
import {Sort} from '@angular/material/sort';

// define function to handle sorting:
sortData(sort: Sort) {
    const data = this.environments.slice();
    if (!sort.active || sort.direction === '') {
        this.dataSource = data;
        return;
    }

    this.dataSource = data.sort((a, b) => {
        const isAsc = sort.direction === 'asc';
        switch (sort.active) {
            case 'name': return compare(a.name, b.name, isAsc);
            case 'username': return compare(a.username, b.username, isAsc);
            default: return 0;
        }
    });
}

function compare(a: number | string, b: number | string, isAsc: boolean) { 
    return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}
```

Comment: When i write `this.dataSource = data`, It shows following error inside if condition: `Type 'Environment[]' is missing the following properties from type 'MatTableDataSource<Environment>': _data, _renderData, _filter, _internalPageChanges, and 16 more.ts(2740)`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the compare.  I'm just following the documentation example they have on the Angular Material site -> https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview.  As far as the Environment[] error, I don't see where you're referencing any Environment types.  Perhaps you could post more of the error and its context?

Comment: We have to specify mat-sort-header="*some name*" so that we can compare using that name in the switch case.